# Button onSubmit undefined state

Tags: reactjs

When I render the page and the list is empty it makes a problem of map I want to know how to make map function wait until the button is pressed which call a redux action. 
I think that it's a problem of state management when the page is rendred the concept list state is an empty list then it fullfill by clicking on button

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { graphGet } from "../../actions/graphActions";

class Graph extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      concepts: []
    };
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
    }
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.props.graphGet(this.props.org);
  }
  render() {
    this.setState((this.state.concepts = this.props.graph.graph.concepts));
    console.log(this.state.concepts);
    const list = (
      <dl>
        {this.state.concepts.map(concept => {
          return (
            <div key={concept.id_cpt}>
              <dt>{concept.fr_cpt}</dt>

              <hr />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </dl>
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        {this.state.concepts ? list : "wait"}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
Graph.prototypes = {
  graphGet: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  graph: state.graph,
  errors: state.errors
});
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { graphGet }
)(Graph);
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I've written an answer for you below. Let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to stackoverflow. Taking a look at your code, I have a few suggestions for you.

1) Do not call state-updating logic inside the `render` method. This causes poor performance issues and often leads to unintended re-renderings. Also  `this.setState((this.state.concepts = this.props.graph.graph.concepts))` is not the proper way of updating your component state.

What you can do is move that logic into a componentDidMount() lifecycle method which will be triggered right after the component has rendered for a first time.

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.setState({
      concepts: this.props.graph.graph.concepts
   });
}
```

2) If you want your list to be populated after the form is submitted, you can store that logic in a function and use it once you've verified that the form has been submitted/button has been clicked. We will also use another state value to check whether the form was submitted before we render the list.

So adding that up, your code will look something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { graphGet } from "../../actions/graphActions";

class Graph extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      concepts: [],
      formSubmitted: false
    };
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
       concepts: this.props.graph.graph.concepts
    })
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
    }
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.graphGet(this.props.org);
    this.setState({
       formSubmitted: true
    })
  }

  createList(){
      return(
         <dl>
            {this.state.concepts.map(concept => {
              return (
                <div key={concept.id_cpt}>
                  <dt>{concept.fr_cpt}</dt>
                <hr />
               </div>
             );
             })}
         </dl>
      )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        {this.state.concepts && this.state.formSubmitted ? this.createList() : 
        "wait"}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
Graph.prototypes = {
  graphGet: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  graph: state.graph,
  errors: state.errors
});
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { graphGet }
)(Graph);
```

Comment: your code works for me with changing 
```
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
    }

    this.setState({
      concepts: this.props.graph.graph.concepts
    });
  }
```